# Django Serialize multiple models in a single view

Tags: django, serialization, model

Here's the scenario, i have two models Offre and Recruteur

```
class Recruteur(models.Model):  
    [...]
    entrepriseName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    [...]

class Offre(models.Model):          
    [...]
    idRecruteur = models.ForeignKey(Recruteur,verbose_name = "idRecruteur", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    [...]
```

And I have the following serializers:

```
class RecruteurByIdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Recruteur
        fields = ( 'entrepriseName',)

class OffreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    recruteur = RecruteurByIdSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:

        model = Offre
        fields = ( 'title', 'dateAjout', 'description', 'recruteur')
```

i expected this result:

[image]

but im getting this instead:

[image]

what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide `source` parameter as below,

```
class OffreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    entrepriseName = RecruteurByIdSerializer(source='idRecruteur', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Offre
        fields = ('title', 'dateAjout', 'description', 'entrepriseName')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this raised 'Recruteur' object is not iterable

Comment: because of `offre_instance.idRecruteur` always an FK object, it can't be `more than one`